# Ubuntu 13.10 wont run progecad in wine

Tags: wine

I'm trying to run Progecad in Wine but it only loads the front screen and then locks up. Also the mouse disappears when over the Progecad window. I've run from command line and get the following info:

```
M56S-S3:~$ wine "c:\Program Files (x86)\progeSOFT\progeCAD 2009 Smart! ENG\icad.exe"
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/p11-kit-trust.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
p11-kit: couldn't load module: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu/pkcs11/gnome-keyring-pkcs11.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
fixme:psdrv:PSDRV_UpdateDevCaps Can't find page
fixme:ole:RemUnknown_QueryInterface No interface for iid {00000019-0000-0000-c000-000000000046}
fixme:ieframe:PersistStreamInit_InitNew (0x3aeaa50)
Killed
M56S-S3:~$ wine --version
wine-1.7.13
```

Any ideas how to fix this?

Answer (score -1):

Running ubuntu 14 with wine with the latest version and progecad ran and loaded fine.  It even put the icon on the desktop Didm't even go to any special settingd.  Running a Acer 5315

Comment: That's not an answer to his problem...  You didn't help the user.  At the best the above is a comment...  Please delete your answer and post it as a comment...